# Is there a feature in Azure DevOps that will allow extraction of repo and branch policy from for IT/SDLC process documentation?

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to be able to use such policies as part of documentation that I can use for internal/external audits on my development process. Is there an easy cohesive way to do that?

Ideally there would be a tool that uses a DSL of some sort to describe the policies and that tool could then be used to set policies as well.

I'm aware that the data I need can probably be retrieved from the REST API. I'll go down that route if I have to (pointers to examples would be appreciated!), but I'm assuming that this is a common need.